# Error code 7321 when running MDX query using openquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

Hi I have written the following MDX query which fetches data from a cube which is on a linked server,

```
USE [BMS_Extracts]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_CQ_SnP_Quotes]    Script Date: 12/17/2015 11:09:23 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER proc [dbo].[usp_CQ_SnP_Quotes] --'2016-Q4'
(
       @FisQuar varchar(20)
)
As

Declare @Mdx nvarchar(max)
Declare @FisMonthparam varchar(20)
Declare @FisMonthloop int

select (FISC_MTH_ID) as Monthloop,concat(left(min(FISC_MTH_ID),4) ,'-M',right(min(FISC_MTH_ID),2))as Monthparam into tbl_CQ_snp_quotes from calendar where cast(FISC_QTR_ID as varchar(10)) = concat(left(@FisQuar,4),right(@FisQuar,1)) group by FISC_MTH_ID

set @FisMonthloop = (select min(Monthloop) from tbl_CQ_snp_quotes)

print @FisMonthloop

while @FisMonthloop <= (select max(Monthloop) from tbl_CQ_snp_quotes)

begin

set @FisMonthparam = (select Monthparam from tbl_CQ_snp_quotes where Monthloop = @FisMonthloop )

print @FisMonthparam

set @mdx= ' insert into CQ_SnP_Quotes
select 
cast(cast([[Dimension - Account]].[Account ID]].[Account ID]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(100)) as bigint) as [Account ID],
cast([[Dimension - Account]].[Account Name]].[Account Name]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(200)) as [Account Name],
cast([[Dimension - Channel]].[Segment]].[Segment]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(30)) as [Segment],
cast(cast([[Dimension - Account Team]].[SR Badge]].[SR Badge]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(100)) as bigint) as [SR Badge],
cast(cast([[Dimension - Account Team]].[SR Mgr Badge]].[SR Mgr Badge]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(100)) as bigint) as [SR Mgr Badge],
cast([[Dimension - Account Team]].[SR Mgr Name]].[SR Mgr Name]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(30)) as [SR Mgr Name],
cast([[Dimension - Account Team]].[SR Name]].[SR Name]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(30)) as [SR Name],
cast(cast([[Dimension - Fiscal Calendar]].[Date]].[Date]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(100)) as datetime) as [Date],
cast([[Dimension - Fiscal Calendar]].[Fiscal Month]].[Fiscal Month]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(30)) as [Fiscal Month],
cast([[Dimension - Fiscal Calendar]].[Fiscal Quarter]].[Fiscal Quarter]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(30)) as [Fiscal Quarter],
cast([[Dimension - Fiscal Calendar]].[Fiscal Week]].[Fiscal Week]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(30)) as [Fiscal Week],
cast([[Dimension - Product]].[Product LOB]].[Product LOB]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(50)) as [Product LOB],
cast([[Dimension - Product]].[Product Brand]].[Product Brand]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(50)) as [Product Brand],
cast(cast([[Base - Quote Offering]].[Quote Num]].[Quote Num]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(100)) as bigint) as [Quote Num],
cast([[Base - Quote Offering]].[Converted Flag]].[Converted Flag]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(30)) as [Converted Flag],
cast([[Custom - Product SnP]].[SnP LOB Level 1]].[SnP LOB Level 1]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(100)) as [SnP LOB Level 1],
cast([[Custom - Product SnP]].[SnP LOB Level 2]].[SnP LOB Level 2]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(100)) as [SnP LOB Level 2],
cast([[Custom - Product SnP]].[SnP LOB Level 3]].[SnP LOB Level 3]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(100)) as [SnP LOB Level 3],
cast([[Custom - Product SnP]].[SnP LOB Level 4]].[SnP LOB Level 4]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(100)) as [SnP LOB Level 4],
cast([[Custom - Product SnP]].[SnP LOB Level 5]].[SnP LOB Level 5]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(100)) as [SnP LOB Level 5],
cast([[Custom - Product SnP]].[SnP LOB Level 6]].[SnP LOB Level 6]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]] as varchar(100)) as [SnP LOB Level 6],
cast(cast([[Measures]].[Margin Quoted SnP]]] as varchar(100)) as float) as [Margin Quoted SnP],
cast(cast([[Measures]].[Revenue Converted SnP]]] as varchar(100)) as float) as [Revenue Converted SnP],
cast(cast([[Measures]].[Revenue Quoted SnP]]] as varchar(100)) as float) as [Revenue Quoted SnP],
cast(cast([[Measures]].[Units Converted SnP]]] as varchar(100)) as float) as [Units Converted SnP],
cast(cast([[Measures]].[Units Quoted SnP]]] as varchar(100)) as float) as [Units Quoted SnP],
cast(cast([[Measures]].[Margin Converted SnP]]] as varchar(100)) as float) as [Margin Converted SnP],
cast(cast([[Measures]].[Margin Quoted SnP Displays]]] as varchar(100)) as float) as [Margin Quoted SnP Displays],
cast(cast([[Measures]].[Units Quoted SnP Displays]]] as varchar(100)) as float) as [Units Quoted SnP Displays],
cast(cast([[Measures]].[Revenue Converted SnP Displays]]] as varchar(100)) as float) as [Revenue Converted SnP Displays],
cast(cast([[Measures]].[Revenue Quoted SnP Displays]]] as varchar(100)) as float) as [Revenue Quoted SnP Displays]

from openquery([AUSDWGSPOLAP1.AUS.AMER.DELL.COM],'' SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Margin Quoted SnP], [Measures].[Revenue Converted SnP], [Measures].[Revenue Quoted SnP], [Measures].[Units Converted SnP], [Measures].[Units Quoted SnP], [Measures].[Margin Converted SnP], [Measures].[Margin Quoted SnP Displays], [Measures].[Units Quoted SnP Displays], [Measures].[Revenue Converted SnP Displays], [Measures].[Revenue Quoted SnP Displays] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Dimension - Account].[Account ID].[Account ID].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Account].[Account Name].[Account Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Channel].[Segment].[Segment].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Account Team].[SR Badge].[SR Badge].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Account Team].[SR Mgr Badge].[SR Mgr Badge].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Account Team].[SR Mgr Name].[SR Mgr Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Account Team].[SR Name].[SR Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Fiscal Calendar].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Fiscal Calendar].[Fiscal Month].[Fiscal Month].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Fiscal Calendar].[Fiscal Quarter].[Fiscal Quarter].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Fiscal Calendar].[Fiscal Week].[Fiscal Week].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Product].[Product LOB].[Product LOB].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Product].[Product Brand].[Product Brand].ALLMEMBERS * [Base - Quote Offering].[Quote Num].[Quote Num].ALLMEMBERS * [Base - Quote Offering].[Converted Flag].[Converted Flag].ALLMEMBERS * [Custom - Product SnP].[SnP LOB Level 1].[SnP LOB Level 1].ALLMEMBERS * [Custom - Product SnP].[SnP LOB Level 2].[SnP LOB Level 2].ALLMEMBERS * [Custom - Product SnP].[SnP LOB Level 3].[SnP LOB Level 3].ALLMEMBERS * [Custom - Product SnP].[SnP LOB Level 4].[SnP LOB Level 4].ALLMEMBERS * [Custom - Product SnP].[SnP LOB Level 5].[SnP LOB Level 5].ALLMEMBERS * [Custom - Product SnP].[SnP LOB Level 6].[SnP LOB Level 6].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dimension - Channel].[Segment].&[CBO LB Public], [Dimension - Channel].[Segment].&[CBO LB PvtEnt], [Dimension - Channel].[Segment].&[CBO MB Public], [Dimension - Channel].[Segment].&[CBO MB PvtEnt] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dimension - Geography].[Country].&[United States] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dimension - Fiscal Calendar].[Fiscal Month].&['+@FisMonthparam+'] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Global SnP Quotations]))) WHERE ( [Dimension - Geography].[Country].&[United States] ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS'')'


Exec sp_executesql @mdx

set @FisMonthloop = @FisMonthloop + 1

end

drop table tbl_CQ_snp_quotes
```

This query used to run successfully before but now it has started giving the following error,

```
OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "AUSDWGSPOLAP1.AUS.AMER.DELL.COM" returned message "The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was completed.".
Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
An error occurred while preparing the query " SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Margin Quoted SnP], [Measures].[Revenue Converted SnP], [Measures].[Revenue Quoted SnP], [Measures].[Units Converted SnP], [Measures].[Units Quoted SnP], [Measures].[Margin Converted SnP], [Measures].[Margin Quoted SnP Displays], [Measures].[Units Quoted SnP Displays], [Measures].[Revenue Converted SnP Displays], [Measures].[Revenue Quoted SnP Displays] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Dimension - Account].[Account ID].[Account ID].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Account].[Account Name].[Account Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Channel].[Segment].[Segment].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Account Team].[SR Badge].[SR Badge].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Account Team].[SR Mgr Badge].[SR Mgr Badge].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Account Team].[SR Mgr Name].[SR Mgr Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Account Team].[SR Name].[SR Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Fiscal Calendar].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Fiscal Calendar].[Fiscal Month].[Fiscal Month].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Fiscal Calendar].[Fiscal Quarter].[Fiscal Quarter].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Fiscal Calendar].[Fiscal Week].[Fiscal Week].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Product].[Product LOB].[Product LOB].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension - Product].[Product Brand].[Product Brand].ALLMEMBERS * [Base - Quote Offering].[Quote Num].[Quote Num].ALLMEMBERS * [Base - Quote Offering].[Converted Flag].[Converted Flag].ALLMEMBERS * [Custom - Product SnP].[SnP LOB Level 1].[SnP LOB Level 1].ALLMEMBERS * [Custom - Product SnP].[SnP LOB Level 2].[SnP LOB Level 2].ALLMEMBERS * [Custom - Product SnP].[SnP LOB Level 3].[SnP LOB Level 3].ALLMEMBERS * [Custom - Product SnP].[SnP LOB Level 4].[SnP LOB Level 4].ALLMEMBERS * [Custom - Product SnP].[SnP LOB Level 5].[SnP LOB Level 5].ALLMEMBERS * [Custom - Product SnP].[SnP LOB Level 6].[SnP LOB Level 6].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dimension - Channel].[Segment].&[CBO LB Public], [Dimension - Channel].[Segment].&[CBO LB PvtEnt], [Dimens...
```

I am new to MDX queries and hence i am not able to find out what the error means. Please let me know how to solve the following error.

Comment: Try running an extremely simple MDX query first to see if there are no connection issues.

Comment: I have run other mdx queries which run successfully.

Comment: @Jayant did you find a solution?

Comment: No i didn't find a solution...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a timeout to me. Can you increase the query timeout for linked servers (and openquery) mentioned here?
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314530

> `configure 'remote query timeout', 0
>
>   go
>
>   reconfigure with override
>
>   go`

Comment: What was the exact query you ran to change the setting?

Comment: I did not write a query i just right clicked on the linked server in server objects and changed the settings. I have run other mdx queries which work fine but i am unable to find why this query does not work.

Comment: @Jayant edited my answer to make it clear what setting I am suggesting. How long did it take before it failed before you change that setting?

Comment: Before it ran for 20+ mins before failing after i increased the query timeout for linked servers to 5000 it now fails after 30+ mins.

Comment: and forgot to mention i ran a simple query directly on the analysis server which did not run. There are other analysis server from which i am able to query data but this particular server was working fine before but now started giving me timeout error.

Comment: You ran a simple query (not the query in your question) "directly" on the SSAS server (meaning via an MDX query window not through a linked server?) and it timed out? The error is actually a timeout? Maybe that SSAS instance needs to be restarted?

Comment: @Jayant 5000 second is 83 minutes. Is that how long it took to timeout over linked server? If not maybe there is another timeout at play.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative rather than a direct answer to your question.

Instead of using `OPENQUERY` try the following `CLR` solution:
https://olapextensions.codeplex.com/

We used to have lots of `OPENQUERY` based `mdx` and have started to move it all onto this CLR stored procedure. Advantages are:

- No linked servers are needed
- No problems with string lengths
- Much much easier data type conversions.